# Find a regular language that becomes non-regular if you cut away the middle third of all words

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Let $A$ be a regular language, let $A'=\{xz\}$ such that for some $y,|x|=|y|=|z|$ and $xyz\in A$.
Show that $A'$ is not necessarily regular language.

This is an excercise of Sipser, I've no idea how to construct $A,A'$ please help someone

Comment: actually I've no idea, I showed it regular if it was "exist $|y|$ such that $|x|=|y|$ and $xy\in A$  " but no idea for this case

Comment: Please note [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/843#843). In general, problems dumps such as this are problematic for SE; we don't really know what your problem is so there's little we can do to teach you fish.

Comment: L = {nonrexxxxxgular} ...

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $A = a^+ b^+ c^+$ and consider $A' \cap a^+c^+$.

Comment: @RickDecker I hope that even in your part of the world, set intersection does not allow you to cut letters out of words. ;)